# How to make display in pdb to work like display in gdb?

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, gdb, pdb

I'm learning to program and I've just switched to problem sets using Python language. Previously, I learned to write some small C programs. So when I debugged C programs, I used gdb and the display command shows the variables and keeps showing them when I use next (n), but the pdb module for Python doesn't behave like that. Is there a way to make display in pdb behave like in gdb?

I get used to running C programs from the terminal and debugging them using GDB also in the terminal, and I found it very effective. I know the programs I worked with are very small, so I would like to know if it's a good idea to keep doing so. And should I do something similarly with python programs using the module PDB?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use Pycharm to check the status of your code. Learn to set the break points and check what is your next time output. There are a lot of useful tools in Pycharm. One thing you may take a look is https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/examining-suspended-program.html